# PyCharm (or python) is not working correctly on my Windows machine (?) - can't do anything under virtualenv (or I'm doing it wrong)?

Tags: windows, python, pycharm

So basically I use Pycharm 2019.2.1 with Python 3.7.4 (I tried reinstalling both if you ask me) and I can't use pip in virtualenv. I tried even calling it with `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt` but it doesn't work.

I did some debugging and it seems that it does not recognize path of PIP:

```
(venv) C:\Users\thesz\PycharmProjects\django_test>pip -V
pip 19.0.3 from c:\users\thesz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

(venv) C:\Users\thesz\PycharmProjects\django_test>
```

Since venv is located under django_test dir.

I don't know what I'm doing really wrong... ? Everything on macOS and Linux seems working fine since year. Only on Windows I got this problem :|

Update:
Strange thing - python virtualenv binaries are in %PATH% so I don't know what is wrong...

```
C:\Users\thesz\PycharmProjects\.virtualenvs\peruccy_pl\Scripts;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2\jbr\\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2\jbr\\bin\server;C:\Program Files\Oculus\Support\oculus-runtime;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\VulkanSDK\1.1.92.1\Bin;C:\P
rogram Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\G
it\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\thesz\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot;C:\Users\thesz\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2\bin;;
C:\Arch;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;C:\Users\thesz\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\bin;C:\Users\thesz\AppData\Local\hyper\app-3.0.2\resources\bin;
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem when I've renamed my project folder.
Unfortunately Pythons virtual environments are not created relocatable.
Running the virtual pip directly gave me a hint in form of an error message:

> Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using
>   '"C:\oldname\venv\scripts\python.exe" 
>   "C:\newname\venv\Scripts\pip.exe" -V'

One solution I didn't try is mentioned in the user guide for the virtualenv tool:
[Making Environments Relocatable](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#making-environments-relocatable)
I don't know if it would work if you've created the venv with the internal venv package like I did.

My solution was to remove the venv folder of my project and create a new virtual environment.
You can export your package list into a requirements.txt before and use it for reinstallation.
The trick to use the correct pip for the export with your broken venv is the path to the virtual python.exe:

```
venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip freeze > requirements.txt
```